# how can NSLOG display multiple variables in one line

Tags: objective-c, nslog

i have three NSString variables 
  `NSString *text1;
    NSString *text2;
    NSString *text3;
    NSLog(@"%@"text1, text2, text3);`
This displays only text1 variable
How can i display all of them in NSLog in one single line?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use a `%@` format specifier for each string:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", string1, string2, string3);
```

Answer (score -3):

DEAR USE NSLOG FORMATER VARIABLE SPECIFIER LIKE THIS

```
int i = 5;
float f = 5.3;
double d = 66.76;
long int li = 22;
short int si = 12;
char c = ‘W’;
signed int sint = 34;
unsigned int uint = –23;
int o = 024;
int h = 0xAD;
long long ll = 45;
long double lf = 34.5;
unsigned long long ull = 12;
NSString *msg = @”NSLog Message”;

//  DO NSLOG

NSLog(@” print int %d”, i);
NSLog(@” print float %f”, f); // use %e for exponential
NSLog(@” print double %f”, d); // use %e for exponential
NSLog(@” print long int %li”, li);
NSLog(@” print short int %i”, si);
NSLog(@” print char %c”, c);
NSLog(@” print signed int %i”, sint);
NSLog(@” print unsigned int %u”, uint);
NSLog(@” print octal %o”, o);
NSLog(@” print hexadecimal %X”, h);
NSLog(@” print long long %lld”, ll);
NSLog(@” print long double %Lf”, lf);
NSLog(@” print unsigned long long %llu”, ull);
NSLog(@” print Object %@”, msg);
```

Comment: for tracing or printing  log  via NSLog you must Specify the specifier as many  Variable you  want to print its Simple way of printing

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT